# getModifierState() not working on dispatched Event

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, keyboard-events, capslock

I'm trying to check for capslock state on page load. So far I've made this event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", capslockCheck)
```

and I'm dispatching an event on page load:

```
const event = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { key: "Tab" })  // the key doesn't matter
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The event listener catches the event correctly but when I try to call `getModifierState("CapsLock")` on this simulated event, it always returns `false`. Whereas when a real key is pressed, it properly returns `true | false` as it should.

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: you cannot emulate physical keyboard events in JS or merge with them with programmatic ones

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Well what should I do then?